# how does docker auto allocate and recycle ports for containers

Tags: docker

When I run docker command

```
docker run -d -P nginx
```

docker will run and auto allocate port for nginx's port 80. If I stop the image and start it again, a new port will be allocated to nginx (normally next one available).

As I found out, the range for port allocation is based on ephemeral port range , in docker case default is 32768 - 61000. (https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/binding/)

How and when does docker recycle ports? Will it go back to 32768 or nearest available?

Answer (score 6):

It took a lot of time for me to find out but `docker` doesn't do much.

I dived into `docker-ce` source files and saw that it uses a function `RequestPortInRange` which simply gives the next available port.

Now, when you run `docker run -d -P nginx` command, docker gives you the first available port in the "ephemeral range" i.e. 32768 - 61000 ( as you pointed out).

Once you destroy /stop the container, it should resume to `32768`, However, it goes to the next available port i.e. `32769` ( on my computer at least).

So, I thought may be it takes sometime for `linux` or any OS to take back the port after the container is destroyed but `netstat -lntu` confirms that the port isn't in use any more.

So, my theory is (which may be entirely wrong, in which case I will be glad to be corrected ), that it creates one instance of `PortAllocator` thing and thus it has a state. so, the next time `docker run -P ...` is called, it goes for the next available port. This is also corroborated by the fact that even when you create other containers, the `docker engine` is providing you the next available port not the previous yet available ones.

I hope i answered your question and i don't know much of `golang` so, forgive any mistake in terminology.